# how to detect an invalid fd/handle

Tags: c, network-programming, apr

I have a server application which handles network clients with an async i/o. The client connections are accepted then added to a descriptor set which can be monitored with poll/epoll/select/etc. I'm using the apr_pollset_poll() apache APR library call to check for descriptors which can be read or written to. This uses epoll/poll/select/etc internally depending on the platform.

Problem is that somehow one of the socket descriptors gets corrupt and the apr_pollset_poll returns errno 10038 which is WSAENOTSOCK: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Unfortunately this causes my application to stop working at all instead of just being able to kick that particular client connection.
If I could somehow ignore or remove this socket from the descriptor set, then it could continue to function and properly read/write the other sockets. I know I should find the root cause which causes the socket to go corrupt, but I need a failsafe workaround.

Once the descriptors are added to the pollset, these are then handled by the OS/kernel and I see no way of retrieving them to be able to iterate on. Maintaining these also in my own list would probably create other problems further down, because on socket close I would need to clean them up somehow which occurs automatically for the in-kernel pollset.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds dire, but it is an emergency situation when it occurs.  So, I suggest going through all the descriptors in your working pollset, and trying to do an operation on that descriptor that will trigger that error if the descriptor is bogus.  For example, you could create a new, temporary pollset and try a non-blocking zero timeout poll operation and see whether you can get the error.

If you've got more than, say, a dozen descriptors in your pollset, you might consider a binary search instead of a one-at-a-time approach.  You could put half your descriptors into the temporary pollset, and then do the operation.  If it fails, you know you've got a bogus descriptor in the set you tried; divide in two and try again; if it does not fail, you can presume the bogus descriptor is in the other set, and you can either validate that the other half fails or assume it will and split the remainder in two and try again.  Keep going until you've isolated the one failing descriptor.  Clearly, if you have several bogus descriptors rather than just one, you may have to repeat the process a few times.

With the one descriptor isolated, you can decide what you need to do about it and how.  And if/when the problem recurs, you can repeat the isolation process.  Clearly, you wouldn't try this unless you detected the problem in the first place.  But when things are going wrong, you need to isolate the problem, and this would (should) achieve that.

Comment: Problem is that once the descriptors are added to the pollset, these are then handled by the OS/kernel and I see no way of retrieving them to be able to iterate on.

Comment: Are you sure?  I've not looked in detail, but you should be able to find out which descriptors are in a poll-set, somehow, if only so you can delete descriptors from the poll-set once it is closed.  If the worst comes to the worst, you'll have to keep an independent record of the descriptors in a given poll-set so that you can do this.

Comment: Looking at the APR documentation for poll-sets, you're clearly expected to know which descriptors are in a given poll-set.  You can add descriptors to a poll-set, or remove (known) descriptors from a poll-set.  It is not clear that there's a way to iterate over the descriptors in a poll-set.

Comment: yes, it is possible to add and remove descriptors, but for that you need to have the descriptor. Unfortunately the list of the descriptors is kept in a private array for the select() and in-kernel for epoll() implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was doing a close() on a socket descriptor which was being polled in another thread and the pollset implementation based on select() does not like this.
On the other hand, it would be possible to modify apr library code to return the descriptor when select detects an invalid socket, or it could even remove it automatically.